# Using Input with React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have simple input which will be available in two different components so to share the state of this input, I decided to use reducer.

Here is my solution:

```
index.js
.....
const Index = () => {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
.............
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
    inputValue: "Testing.com"
}

const nameReducerr = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "INPUT_CHANGE":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {inputValue: action.text})
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default nameReducerr
```

here is my component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"

function inputData() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const inputValue = useSelector(state => state.inputValue);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
          dispatch(setName(event.target.value));
        }
      };
    
      console.log('input value', inputValue);
    return (
        <div>
                <input
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control address"
                    name=""
                  />
                  <h1>Name: {name}</h1>
                  <h1>Input Value: {inputValue}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default input data
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error.

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

What am I doing wrong here? thx

Comment: You are dispatching a `SetStateAction`  (`setName`) instead of an object with a `type` and `text`. You want to `dispatch({ type: 'INPUT_CHANGE', text: event.target.value })`

Comment: Hi bro this give me error : `input value undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`setName` is your setter for your local react state and has nothing to do with redux - so it's result cannot be dispatched. You will need to write an action creator instead.

Generally, `useState` is local component state. So it also does not select the value from the redux store in any way, which will be your next problem. You will need to use `useSelector` instead.

Also, you are using a very outdated style of redux here which we do not really recommend any more. To learn modern redux, please follow the official tutorials over at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index - you will write a lot less and more secure code in the end.

Comment: Hi bro, okay so can you provide a simple demo of how to handle input in redux using modern way, thanks for the link I will be checking

Comment: The problems you have here have no correlation with "old vs modern redux", that was more of a general hint that you are probably following a very outdated tutorial.

The problem here is that you are mixing the React hook "useState" with Redux, two completely independent concepts.

Just giving you the solution here won't help you learning. And it's not a small error to be corrected, it is a fundamental thing so I really think you should re-read my answer that tells you all the things to use instead and then try on your own.

Comment: Yes I am following this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOO5hit7s0U handling input with redux, if you have a modern tutorial on how to handle input using redux I will appreciate

Comment: any way followed your link documentation and solved the issue